# Google Places API - Counting the total number of places in a given radius around a lat / long?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Slightly unusual request, but just wondered if anyone knows of a way to calculate the total number of places in the Google Places places database within a given radius (or polygon) around a lat / long?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice question. It will work dude

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to query the Places API for the total number of places that fall within a given radius in the Google database. When you query the Places API, the maximum number of results that will be returned is 20 (twenty) as described in this question/answers: [What is the proper way to use the radius parameter in the Google Places API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10615275/1314132).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misreading the question, but here goes. Check out the [Places API example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests); its search results is an array, so you can read `results.length` as the number of places found (returned by the request, see below). The coverage radius around a latLng or rectangular bounds is set in the request.

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Idea is perfect. But, I didnt get the value till now. Please help

Comment: I got it thank you for your idea..., Little bit changes is there --               var place = results.length; Like this u have to do. It will work.