# Get total number of places using Google Maps API

Tags: php, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to search some category of places supported from supported [types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types) like.. Getting Total number of museum in United States.

After reading these docs I found that we should do that search by this.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters

Even it shows the entire json..

I tried something like this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=MYAPI

But How can I exactly get only total numbers of Museum available in United States.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to query the Places API for the total number of places that fall within a given radius in the Google database. When you query the Places API, the maximum number of results that will be returned is 20 (twenty) as described in this question/answers: [What is the proper way to use the radius parameter in the Google Places API?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615275/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-the-radius-parameter-in-the-google-places-api)

Comment: Is there any possiblity to get the number of counts only from API.. ?

Comment: As per my understanding and experience,No, there is no way for that.